# Rails with Searchkick: getting results with a joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm starting to use searchkick in my app, and I have two models: House and Address (which belongs to a house).

House:

```
class House < ApplicationRecord
 searchkick
 has_one :address,  dependent: :destroy
end
```

Address:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
 searchkick
 belongs_to :house
end
```

In my controller I have

```
def index
 if params[:term].present?
  @houses = House.search(params[:term])
 else
  @houses = House.search('*')
 end
end
```

Right now, searchkick is working when I search for house data which is in the table `houses`, but if for example I look for a field in the Addresses table, I do not get any result at all.
Is it possible to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to index addresses also. To do that add the below code to your `House` model:

```
def search_data
  attributes.merge(
      address_city: self.address.try(:city),
      address_zip: self.address.try(:zip)
  )
end
```

Feel free to modify the above code based on your fields in the `Address` model.

Also, after adding the above code, don't forget to reindex.

Comment: well it isn't really working: `undefined local variable or method `addresses' for #<Class:0x00007fb78071ddd0>`, how can I do that? I didn't know I could use other models inside a model class

Comment: That was just an example. To give you an exact answer, You will have to provide us with the associations you have defined in your `House` model.

Comment: and also the columns you've in the other table.

Comment: @noloman Updated the answer. Since you've not provided the fields available in `address` model, I've assumed that you will have city and zip in addresses table

Comment: Change the attributes for merging based on the fields in your `addresses` table.

Comment: And once it is done, Don't forget to reindex. This is important! :)

Comment: even if I do `addresses_city: address.try(&:city)` it says `undefined local variable or method address for #<Class:0x00007fb786de2c50>` that's why I was asking if it's possible to call `address` from the `house` model

Comment: Yes, it should be possible!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184212/discussion-between-noloman-and-abhilash-reddy).

Comment: I've updated the answer, Can your try appending `address` with `self`. If you still get an error do you mind sharing your model here?